# CSS importance order

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align content of one column in table to right using Twitter Bootstrap.

The problem is, that `.text-right` class doesn't work for `<td>` element. Applying `text-align:right` style works, but I'm curious why class applied to element has lower priority than general element style.

http://jsfiddle.net/ctANw/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I'm curious why class applied to element has lower priority then general element style.`

Because inline styles have the greatest specificity in CSS (besides using the `!important` keyword)

Think of specificity as four numbers (0,0,0,0)

- Inline styles are the first - highest precedence
- ID selectors are the second number
- Pseudo-classes, attribute selectors and classes are the third
- Type selectors are the fourth (this also includes pseudo-elements)
- The universal selector `*` has a specificity of 0, anything will override it.

Using that you should be able to figure out how to override a particular selector

Comment: The question is not about inline style `text-align:right` vs class `text-right` but `td` style vs .text-right class. Shouldn't class be more important then general `td` style?

Comment: Yes it should but in your example it seems like your comparing inline styles

Comment: I'm not comparing anything. Inline style was just an addition. I wanna find out why elements style overwrites class style.

Comment: I see .. I'm fairly sure it is because there are more specific selectors already targeting the `td` e.g. (`.table td`) on line 192 in bootstrap.min.css so you would need to be more specific if you want to override it.

Comment: I think so too. But still.. it's illogical. :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: You are simply assigning a class to an element which already has a class *and* a type selector applied to it. `.table td` == (0,0,1,1) vs `.text-right` == (0,0,1,0), the former takes precedence .. you can clearly see this in your browsers dev. tools

Comment: One more thing about these numbers. Where can I read about them? :)

Comment: The beginning [**of this article**](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/17/taming-advanced-css-selectors/) has some good info on specificity

Answer (score 1):

It's just that the .table td rule on line 192 which has "text-align: left;" is overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the [Specificity hierarchy](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Every selector has its place in the specificity hierarchy. There are four distinct categories which define the specificity level of a given selector:

1. Inline styles (Presence of style in document). An inline style lives
   within your XHTML document. It is attached directly to the element
   to be styled. E.g. `<h1 style="color: #fff;">`
2. IDs (# of ID selectors) ID is an identifier for your page elements,
   such as `#div`.
3. Classes, attributes and pseudo-classes (# of class selectors). This
   group includes .classes, [attributes] and pseudo-classes such as
   `:hover`, `:focus` etc.
4. Elements and pseudo-elements (# of Element (type) selectors).
   Including for instance `:before` and `:after`.

Comment: I'd mention `!important`, too

Comment: I know that. :| The problem is, that element (4.) is overwriting  the class. (3.)